# IISでTCPのrwndとcwndの値を変更する方法

Tags: windows

IISでTCPのrwndとcwndの値を変更する方法をご存知の方がいましたら教えていただけると助かります。
IIS8.5です。
もしかしたらIISの設定ではなくもっと低レイヤーのコマンドを打つ必要があるかもしれませんが、目的はIISWebアプリケーションの高速化です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決となりますが、こちらにコマンドが記載されていました。
https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh826132.aspx

Answer (score 1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/magazine/2007.01.cableguy.aspx

によると随分昔から自動調整のようですが。
外部から指定する方法は存在していないのではないでしょうか。
大きくしたとしても、ブラウザがウィンドウサイズの変更ネゴを了承してくれなければどうしようもないですし。